# Saving a file generated with Excel (2003) Interop on IIS 7.0 Windows 2008 x64

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net

I have a script that generates an Excel spreadsheet that appears to be working all the way until it reaches the SaveAs() call.  I've tried changing DCOM settings, Application pool settings, impersonation settings in web.config and none of them seem to do anything.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Obvious question I suppose, but have you checked you have access to the folder where the spreadsheet is being saved? From the tags I'd guess this is being done from an ASP.Net page on a web server in which case it will be running as either the user opening the page if you're using authentication or as, erm, something else if it's anonymous access.

JR

Comment: That was the first thing I checked.  I was able to write a simple text file with no problems so the folder permissions doesn't seem to be the problem.  I've tried writing to other folders that allow Everyone full access but Excel interop keeps throwing an exception.

Perhaps it's a Session 0 problem?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running your worker processes in 32-bit?  If not see http://blogs.iis.net/hosterposter/archive/2007/02/12/getting-64-bit-or-32-bit-applications-working-on-iis-6-0-x64.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing Excel automation on the server side? Then if I were you, I would consider the advice provided in KB 257757.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757